# No incrementa la función para para contar elementos de un array

Tags: php, array, funciones, revisión-de-código, loops

Tengo un array definido con notas de alumnos de la siguiente manera:

```
$arrayinicial = array('Juan'=> $njuan, 'María'=> $nmaria, 'Jose'=>$njose);
```

La función que tengo es la siguiente:

```
 function ceros(array $arrayinicial) { 
            $i = 0; 
            foreach ($arrayinicial as $llave => $x) 
            if ($x = 0);
            $i++;
            return $i; 
            }
            $ceros = ceros($arrayinicial);
        echo "Han sacado un 0 ".$ceros." personas </br>";
         }
```

Cuando entran 3 0 por el formulario me dice que sólo hay uno

Comment: Simpre estas devolviendo 1; seguro incluso si no pones ningun **0**; el *if($x=0);* esta finalizando el *foreach* sin que se incremente si es o no *0*; así mismo *$x=0* debe ser **$x==0**. Revisa tu algoritmo, tu pseudocódigo y entonces codifica.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function ceros(array $arrayinicial) { 
    $ceros = 0; 
    foreach ($arrayinicial as $alumno => $nota) 
        if ($nota == 0)
            $ceros++;
    return $ceros; 
}
```

if ($x = 0); Te falta == para comprar y te sobra el ;